# How ws() works in Jenkins groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

## Case 1

Below scripted pipeline code works with `workSpace` as workspace for npm build process, where `npm install` is able to find `package.json` file in `workSpace`

```
ws(workSpace){

                def commandString = "npm install ; npm rebuild node-sass ; ng build"
                executeCommand(commandString, repositoryName)
}
```

where `executeCommand()` is,

```
def executeCommand(commandString, component){

        BUILD_FULL = sh (
                        script: commandString,
                        returnStatus: true
                    ) == 0
        echo "     Build status for ${component}: ${BUILD_FULL}"

}
```

---

## Case 2

But, below code with same `workSpace` as workspace used for npm build process, but `npm install` is not able to find `package.json` in `workSpace`

```
        ws(workSpace){

            buildStatus = sh (
                                returnStdout: true,
                                script: '''
                                        npm install // Install dependencies
                                        npm rebuild node-sass // Convert scss to css native
                                        ng build --prod --configuration=cloud // Build 
                                        '''
                            ) == 0
            print "User@ Build status for ${repositoryName} is ${buildStatus}"

        } // end ws()
```

below is the error in case 2

```
+ npm install // Install dependencies
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "../../../../../.." as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2019-01-07T16_20_20_339Z-debug.log
```

---

How does `ws()` works in groovy?

Comment: Putting comments inside a literal string will include them in the literal string. You should probably remove those from your `script:`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Make sense

Answer (score 2):

you should remove comments an replace them with pipe to run task one after the other finish

```
sh '''
npm install ||
npm rebuild node-sass ||
ng build --prod --configuration=cloud 
'''
```

let me know if if works!